# Text to speech solution?

Tags: javascript, speech-synthesis

I’m the webmaster for a non-profit ([readnowatx.org](https://readnowatx.org)) dedicated to promoting literacy.  The site includes a page to teach reading that uses MP3s generated by AWS Polly to “read” displayed text aloud (http://jpreadsite.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/readnow%20v9/player.html).
The original page used JavaScript TTS that generated the audio from text, but the voice quality of Polly is superior to what I could get from JavaScript.  But maintenance is more difficult, as the page displays more than 800 individual sentences, and a MP3 file is required each one.
Options I am considering include using IBM Watson to generate the TTS “on the fly” if that is possible or getting a custom voice (donated or purchased) that can be integrated into JavaScript.  Any recommendations?